# How to support earlier API versions in Facebook Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

Facebook SDK for Android supports API 15 or higher: [Facebook SDK for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

My app can even run on Android 2.3 so my minimum API is version 9. When I try to import Facebook SDK, it asks me to change the minimum API to 15. But doing that will result in losing potential users. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You don't. That's the minimum the Facebook SDK supports.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only use the Graph API, you can send requests to the [REST Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) without the official Facebook SDK. You can create a simple wrapper that sends traditional HTTP requests to the Graph API.

To obtain an access token, you can setup [a simple website that holds the login button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) and shows the Facebook login dialog, redirecting to your site where you can pass the access token to your Java code via [custom scheme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html#scheme).

This way you don't need to use the official Facebook SDK, keeping your minimum API where you'd want it to be.